# Fail to build conda recipe for github repo

Tags: python-2.7, package, conda

I am struggling to build a conda recipe for my conda environment on Python 2.7 (Windows 64) with the [osrm github repository](https://github.com/ustroetz/python-osrm).

My bld.bat file is:

```
python setup.py install
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

meta.yaml

```
package:
  name: osrm
  version: 0.11.1

source:
    git_url: git@github.com/ustroetz/python-osrm.git
    git_rev: 0.11.1

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
  run:
    - python

test:
  imports: 
    - osrm

about:
  home: https://github.com/ustroetz/python-osrm
  license: MIT
  license_file: LICENSE
```

When I run `conda build osrm/` I get the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop> conda build osrm/
BUILD START: osrm-0.11.1-py36_0
updating index in: C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\win-64
updating index in: C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\noarch

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    certifi:        2017.1.23-py36_0 conda-forge
    pip:            9.0.1-py36_0     conda-forge
    python:         3.6.0-2          conda-forge
    setuptools:     33.1.1-py36_0    conda-forge
    vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25420-0     conda-forge
    wheel:          0.29.0-py36_0    conda-forge
    wincertstore:   0.2-py36_0       conda-forge

Cloning into 'C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_149017
done.
checkout: '0.11.1'
error: pathspec '0.11.1' did not match any file(s) known to g
Warning: failed to download source.  If building, will try ag
Error was:
Command '['C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe', 'checkout',
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-build-script.
    sys.exit(conda_build.cli.main_build.main())
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_bui
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_bui
    noverify=args.no_verify)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_bui
    need_source_download=need_source_download, config=config)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_bui
    config=config)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_bui
    assert not need_source_download, "Source download failed.
AssertionError: Source download failed.  Please investigate.
```

I am really struggling with this one, why am I getting this error?

Comment: This fails because `0.11.1` is not a Git tag in that repository (see https://github.com/ustroetz/python-osrm/tags).

Comment: Hey @darthbith thanks for your idea. Actually this was it. The problem is when I now run the command without the tag, I get a new different error message (which is too long to post it here). The final lines say:

  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmd.exe', '/c', 'bld.bat']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: So it seems like the bld.bat file is not configured rightly.

I did all the process in the conda build documentations but something's still wrong here

Comment: So at this point, it seems like it would be best to open a new question and post the complete text of the error message in that post.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway! The link to the new question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055560/error-on-building-python-conda-recipe just in case you have an idea

Comment: I gave an answer over there, take a look. And please consider marking this question as "Answered" by clicking the green check if it solved your problem from this question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is because `0.11.1` is not a Git tag in that repository, so git fails at the checkout stage. See: https://github.com/ustroetz/python-osrm/tags

Comment: Looking at the link, I don't see any tags. What's the solution in this case?

Comment: You can specify a particular branch to build