# Error on building python conda recipe

Tags: python, build, conda, recipe, osrm

After I got help on how to refer to a github repository in my conda recipe for [the osrm github repository](https://github.com/ustroetz/python-osrm) I get an error message and script is stopping.

My bld.bat file is:

```
python setup.py install
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

meta.yaml

```
package:
  name: osrm
  version: 0.11.1

source:
    git_url: git@github.com/ustroetz/python-osrm.git

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
  run:
    - python

test:
  imports: 
    - osrm

about:
  home: https://github.com/ustroetz/python-osrm
  license: MIT
  license_file: LICENSE
```

When I run conda build osrm/ I get the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop> conda build osrm/
BUILD START: osrm-0.11.1-py36_0
updating index in: C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\win-64
updating index in: C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\noarch

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    certifi:        2017.1.23-py36_0 conda-forge
    pip:            9.0.1-py36_0     conda-forge
    python:         3.6.1-0          conda-forge
    setuptools:     33.1.1-py36_0    conda-forge
    vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25420-0     conda-forge
    wheel:          0.29.0-py36_0    conda-forge
    wincertstore:   0.2-py36_0       conda-forge

BUILD START: osrm-0.11.1-py36_0
updating index in: C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\win-64
updating index in: C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\noarch

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    certifi:        2017.1.23-py36_0 conda-forge
    pip:            9.0.1-py36_0     conda-forge
    python:         3.6.1-0          conda-forge
    setuptools:     33.1.1-py36_0    conda-forge
    vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25420-0     conda-forge
    wheel:          0.29.0-py36_0    conda-forge
    wincertstore:   0.2-py36_0       conda-forge


WARNING: conda-build appears to be out of date. You have version 2.1.7 but the
latest version is 2.1.8. Run

conda update -n root conda-build

to get the latest version.

Cloning into 'C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work'...
done.
checkout: 'HEAD'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/_conda_cache_origin_head'.
==> git log -n1 <==

fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
commit 3c7980817e3ddd95c5e7e0863140311fa839bd3d
Merge: 2ab1f6c db984ef
Author: Uli Stroetz <uli@door2door.io>
Date:   Mon Oct 31 18:26:35 2016 +0100

    Merge pull request #6 from mthh/master

    Update to OSRM v5 API

==> git describe --tags --dirty <==

commit 3c7980817e3ddd95c5e7e0863140311fa839bd3d
Merge: 2ab1f6c db984ef
Author: Uli Stroetz <uli@door2door.io>
Date:   Mon Oct 31 18:26:35 2016 +0100

    Merge pull request #6 from mthh/master

    Update to OSRM v5 API

==> git status <==

On branch _conda_cache_origin_head
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/_conda_cache_origin_head'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Package: osrm-0.11.1-py36_0
source tree in: C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "CONDA_BUILD=1"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaco
srm_1490644832910\_b_env"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "ARCH=64"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "PREFIX=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-
832910\_b_env"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "SYS_PREFIX=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "SYS_PYTHON=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\py

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "SUBDIR=win-64"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "SRC_DIR=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda
4832910\work"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "HTTPS_PROXY="

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "HTTP_PROXY="

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "DIRTY="

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "ROOT=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "PYTHON=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-
832910\_b_env\python.exe"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "PY3K=1"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "STDLIB_DIR=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\co
0644832910\_b_env\Lib"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "SP_DIR=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-
832910\_b_env\Lib\site-packages"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "PY_VER=3.6"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "CONDA_PY=36"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "PERL=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bl
2910\_b_env\perl.exe"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "PERL_VER=5.20.3"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "LUA=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld
910\_b_env\lua.exe"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "LUA_INCLUDE_DIR=C:\Users\Samuel\Anacond
m_1490644832910\_b_env\include"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "LUA_VER=5.2"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "PKG_NAME=osrm"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "PKG_VERSION=0.11.1"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "PKG_BUILDNUM="

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "PKG_BUILD_STRING=py36_0"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "RECIPE_DIR=C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\osrm

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "CPU_COUNT=4"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "SHLIB_EXT=.dll"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "PATH=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bl
2910\_b_env;C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users
3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\Library\usr\bin;;C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_14906448
rary\bin;C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\Scripts;C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3
1490644832910\_b_env\Scripts;C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\Library\bin
s\Gurobi\win64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System3
S\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Ki
erformance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27
es (x86)\GDAL\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\include;C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda
rs\Samuel\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Us
ta\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps; C:\Program Fi

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "SCRIPTS=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda
4832910\_b_env\Scripts"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "LIBRARY_PREFIX=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda
_1490644832910\_b_env\Library"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "LIBRARY_BIN=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\c
90644832910\_b_env\Library\bin"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "LIBRARY_INC=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\c
90644832910\_b_env\Library\include"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "LIBRARY_LIB=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\c
90644832910\_b_env\Library\lib"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "R=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\o
0\_b_env\Scripts\R.exe"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "CYGWIN_PREFIX=/cygdrive/c/Users/Samuel/
bld/osrm_1490644832910/_b_env"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "SYSTEMROOT=C:\WINDOWS"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "WINDIR=C:\WINDOWS"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "CONDA_BUILD_STATE=BUILD"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set MSSdk=1

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set PY_VCRUNTIME_REDIST=C:\Users\Samuel\Anac
osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\Library\bin\vcruntime140.dll

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "VS_VERSION=14.0"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "VS_MAJOR=14"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "VS_YEAR=2015"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "CMAKE_GENERATOR=Visual Studio 14 2015 W

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/AI;/AL;/OUT;/out"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=CL"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visua
mmon7\Tools\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "INCLUDE=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda
4832910\_b_env\Library\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program
dows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared;C:\Program
dows Kits\8.1\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt;"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>set "LIB=C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld
910\_b_env\Library\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files
its\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64;"

C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\work>call "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\Scripts\acti
ers\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env"

(C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env) C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm
ork>REM ===== end generated header =====

(C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env) C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm
ork>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating osrm.egg-info
writing osrm.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to osrm.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to osrm.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to osrm.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'osrm.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'osrm.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'osrm.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\osrm
copying osrm\core.py -> build\lib\osrm
copying osrm\extra.py -> build\lib\osrm
copying osrm\__init__.py -> build\lib\osrm
creating build\bdist.win-amd64
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\osrm
copying build\lib\osrm\core.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\osrm
copying build\lib\osrm\extra.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\osrm
copying build\lib\osrm\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\osrm
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\osrm\core.py to core.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\osrm\extra.py to extra.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\osrm\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying osrm.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying osrm.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying osrm.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying osrm.egg-info\requires.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying osrm.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating dist
creating 'dist\osrm-0.11.1-py3.6.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing osrm-0.11.1-py3.6.egg
Copying osrm-0.11.1-py3.6.egg to c:\users\samuel\anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-
Adding osrm 0.11.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\users\samuel\anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\osrm-0.11.1-py
Processing dependencies for osrm==0.11.1
Searching for matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    install_requires=requirements
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148,
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955,
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974,
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\comma
line 67, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\comma
line 117, in do_egg_install
    cmd.run()
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\comma
py", line 411, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\comma
py", line 655, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\comma
py", line 702, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\comma
py", line 747, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__
 846, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__
 1118, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__
 1130, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\comma
py", line 662, in easy_install
    not self.always_copy, self.local_index
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\packa
ne 639, in fetch_distribution
    self.find_packages(requirement)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\packa
ne 480, in find_packages
    self.scan_url(self.index_url + requirement.unsafe_name + '/')
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\packa
ne 812, in scan_url
    self.process_url(url, True)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\packa
ne 317, in process_url
    "Be sure to add all dependencies in the meta.yaml  url=%sr" % url)
RuntimeError: Setuptools downloading is disabled in conda build. Be sure to add all dependencies in the
ttps://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/r

(C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm_1490644832910\_b_env) C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\conda-bld\osrm
ork>if errorlevel 1 exit 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-build-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(conda_build.cli.main_build.main())
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py", line 334, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py", line 325, in execute
    noverify=args.no_verify)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\api.py", line 97, in build
    need_source_download=need_source_download, config=config)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py", line 1502, in build_tree
    config=config)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\build.py", line 1104, in build
    windows.build(m, build_file, config=config)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\windows.py", line 231, in build
    check_call_env(cmd, cwd=src_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\utils.py", line 616, in check_call_env
    return _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ(subprocess.check_call, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_build\utils.py", line 612, in _func_defaulting
on
    return func(_args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmd.exe', '/c', 'bld.bat']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Why am I getting this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you need to list all the dependencies of the package in the `meta.yaml` file - apparently, you've missed one because of this error message:

```
RuntimeError: Setuptools downloading is disabled in conda build. Be sure to add all dependencies in the meta.yaml
```

Given the package it was looking for prior to the start of the traceback,

```
Processing dependencies for osrm==0.11.1
Searching for matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
```

I suspect this particular error is because Matplotlib isn't in your dependencies, but there may be others as well.